# Why does with statement work with sqlite3 but not with mysql.connection?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, with-statement

when I run the following code:

```
with sqlite3.connect("example.db") as con:
    c=con.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id,name) ")
```

everything works fine.

But when I use a `mysql.connector`:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb

with mariadb.connect(user='root', password='root', database='publications') as con:
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id INT,name VARCHAR(45))")
```

I get this error:

```
File "<...>", line 4, in <module>
with mariadb.connect(user='root', password='root', database='publications') as con:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Can someone tell me the reason for that? As I have read in ["PEP 343 -- The "with" Statement"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to use an object with a with-statement, you need to implement the `__enter__()` and the `__exit__()`-method. So it seems like it is implemented in `sqlite3` but not in `mysql.connection`. But what is the reason for this? Is there a deeper reason or has `Mysql` just not implemented it?

Thank you :)

Comment: Specifying column datatype in MySQL/MariaDB is compulsory.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `WITH` was added in MySQL 8.  Is this what you have?

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite columns don't have a type (a default type). In MySQL columns need to have an explicit type. Add the type and problem solved.

For example, the SQL statement could be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int, name varchar(50))
```

Comment: sorry, this was an error in the example code, the actual error which puzzled me has already happened in the line with the `with` statement